# Manipulate JavaScript using Java

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I'm connecting to a webserver with a specific JavaScript. (Using HttpURLConnection atm)
What i need is a connection that makes it possible to manipulate a JavaScript function. 
Afterwards i want to run the whole JavaScript again.

I want the following function always to return "new FlashSocketBackend()"

```
function createBackend() {
    if (flashSocketsWork) {
        return new FlashSocketBackend()
    } else {
        return new COMETBackend()
    }
}
```

Do i have to use HtmlUnit for this? 
Whats the easiest way to connect, manipulate and re-run the script?

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean for "to manipulate a JavaScript function"? You want that browser send JavaScript code to server, or that after connection, the server is able to call javascript function on client?

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense. HttpURLConnection is a Java class. There is essentially no relation between Java and JavaScript. Maybe try to rephrase your question.

Comment: Yea i want to change a function which will be called by the server afterwards.

Comment: @Graham Clark, HttpURLConnection is the class i use to connect to the server where the JavaScript is stored

Comment: @Tom That's nice. However, HUC only deals with the transferring of data (It only does "what a web-browser does" when connecting to a webpage). *You'll* need to make it do something useful. E.g is it a JavaScript file? Can you use WebDAV? Is there other support on the server or a custom protocol/Rest API? Etc. This is far too broad to be "a real question".

Comment: @Tom, ok I misunderstood your question. It kinda reads like you're connecting to the webserver with JavaScript. I guess the answer will depend on what you want to do to the JavaScript. If it's a simple change, then it's just string manipulation. If it's more complex, then I have no idea. Maybe edit your question and add some details...

Comment: The server is not mine and i can't change anything on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HtmlUnit you indeed can do it.

Even though you can not manipulate an existing JS function, you can however execute what JavaScript code you wish on an existing page.

Example:

```
WebClient htmlunit = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = htmlunit.getPage("http://www.google.com");
page = page.executeJavaScript("<JS code here>").getNewPage(); 

//manipulate the JS code and re-excute
page =  page.executeJavaScript("<manipulated JS code here>").getNewPage();

//manipulate the JS code and re-excute
page =  page.executeJavaScript("<manipulated JS code here>").getNewPage();
```

more:
http://www.aviyehuda.com/2011/05/htmlunit-a-quick-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot is probably to use [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) — an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely in Java. Loading your page with a `window.location` and hopefully running your JavaScript function. I read sometime before [Bringing the Browser to the Server](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/) and seemed possible.